# Azure Stream Analytics In-Consistent Outputs

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics

I am using Azure Stream Analytics as a pass through to land data into data lake store.

Source file is | delimited csv.  Output is also | delimited csv.  Incoming file in blob storage is formatted correctly when examining in notepad++ that each line ends with a line feed. No crazy transformations, just a simple select *.

After Azure Stream Analytics processes the file and moves it into blob storage, I am getting inconsistencies in ending line feeds.  Some will be LF (Line Feed) and others will be LFCR (Line Feed Carriage Return).  This causes problems down the pipeline when trying to process data using U-SQL.

Has anyone ran into this?  My sample file was 5000 records.

Comment: Hi Jason, is it related to the non-escaped " that we discussed on another thread? If you can send me the sample in private message, I can investigate on this.

Comment: Yes @Jean-Sébastien, this is the same issue.